# Caddy reverse proxy to multiple sites with docker, scalability

Tags: docker, reverse-proxy, caddyfile

I'm trying to set-up a simple Caddy server on host machine to redirect multiple domains to multiple web servers hosted in Docker containers.

This configuration tells Caddy to proxy all requests for each domain to a different Docker container running on the host machine.

```
example1.com {
    reverse_proxy / http://localhost:8000
}

example2.com {
    reverse_proxy / http://localhost:8001
}

exampleN.com { ... }
```

```bash
docker run -d --name web-container1 -p 8000:80 web-image1
docker run -d --name web-container2 -p 8001:80 web-image2
docker run -d --name web-containerN -p 800N:80 web-imageN
```

What are some more scalable solutions for managing multiple websites and containers when mapping ports to container ports becomes impractical as the number of websites and containers grows?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do, is run a reverse proxy container that listens for new caddy instances and automatically add them to the reverse proxy configuration (gracefully).

I found [caddy-docker-proxy](https://github.com/lucaslorentz/caddy-docker-proxy) the last night and implemented it quite simply with 2 different docker compose files.

The neat thing is that the site holds its own caddy reverse proxy information in the labels section, which I pushed up into my .env file.

My reverse proxy:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  caddy:
    image: lucaslorentz/caddy-docker-proxy:2.3
    ports:
      - "${PORT_HTTP}:80"
      - "${PORT_HTTPS}:443"
      - "${PORT_HTTPS}:443/udp"
    environment:
      - CADDY_INGRESS_NETWORKS=caddy
    networks:
      - caddy
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - caddy_data:/data
    restart: unless-stopped
    labels:
      caddy.email: hello@mydomain.com

  portainer:
    image: portainer/portainer-ce:latest
    restart: unless-stopped

    networks:
      - caddy

    labels:
      caddy: "portainer.mydomain.com"
      caddy.reverse_proxy: "{{upstreams 9000}}"


volumes:
  caddy_data: {}

networks:
  caddy:
    name: caddy
    external: true
```

Then my template of sites runs like this (plus additional services)

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  caddy:
    image: caddy:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - $PWD/Caddyfile:/etc/caddy/Caddyfile
      - www-dir:/var/www/html
      - caddy_data:/data
      - caddy_config:/config
    networks:
      - web_server
      - caddy
    labels:
      caddy: ${WEBSITE_URL}
      caddy.reverse_proxy: "{{upstreams 80}}"

volumes:
  caddy_data:
  caddy_config:
  
  www-dir:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      o: bind
      type: none
      device: $PWD/www-${ENV}
  
  caddy:
    name: caddy
    external: true
```

Note that you need to create the network first:

```
docker network create caddy
```

Then start them all in the order you choose:

```
docker compose up --build -d
```